# angular: wait for asynchronous data

Tags: angular

I am using Angular and trying to validate the user credentials for a login page in my service.ts file by sending the request to a backend. I want to wait for the server response in my component.ts file but, I am unable to do so.

Here's my code:

> Service.ts

```
check_authentication(mail: string, passcode: string)
{
  const params = new HttpParams().set('id', mail).set('id2', passcode);

  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', this.test, {params, responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData => {
    if(responseData == 'Authorized')
    {
        this.check = true;

    }
    else
    {
        this.check = false;

    }
  }
  ,error => {
    console.log("Error occurred while trying to login "+ error.message);
  });
}

isAuthenticated() : boolean
{
  return this.check;
}
```

> Component.ts

```
onSubmit()
{
  
  this.auth.check_authentication(this.mail, this.code);

  //this if-else block isn't executing as somehow the response from the server isn't there yet.
  //I want to wait for the response here
  if(this.auth.isAuthenticated() == true)
  {
    console.log("submit button called here");

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
   
  else if(this.auth.isAuthenticated() == false)
  {
    this.unAuthorized = true; //as I am throwing an alert if user login fails
  }

   console.log("Printing this to see if this function is being called correctly"); //this executes 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `check_authenticationl` is asynchronous, meaning that the value is not ready before you check if the user is authenticated or not. There are several approaches to solve this. One is to let `check_authentication` return a Promise.

In the service:

```
    check_authentication(mail: string, passcode: string)
    {
      const params = new HttpParams().set('id', mail).set('id2', passcode);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // create a promise that resolves after the api returns a response

      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', this.test, {params, responseType: "text"})
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        if(responseData == 'Authorized') {
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            resolve(false);
        }
      }, error => {
        console.log("Error occurred while trying to login "+ error.message);
        reject();
      });
    })
      
    }
```

In the Component

```
    this.auth.check_authentication(this.mail, this.code).then( isAuth => {
      if(isAuth){

      }else{

      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying to use the promise but, seems like I was running into syntax error. :)

Comment: I haven't tested the code I wrote, so there might be some syntax errors there :S